# How to hide files on USB [Python]

Tags: python, security, usb, data-hiding

The goal is to prevent unauthorized copying from USB Drive. I need to block visibility of selected files on other devices (upon USB insertion) not using attribute "Hidden". Is there a way to do that theoretically?

Comment: If they can access the file they can copy it, since they can just do `cat filename > newfilename`

Comment: The  only solution is to change the ownership of the file and make it non-readable by ordinary users, and then require them to use a set-uid program to access the file.